# How to query openldap accesslog by reqStart attribute

Tags: openldap

I am probably missing something simple in LDAP filter syntax here, I am trying to query the database created by the `accesslog` overlay in OpenLDAP by the `reqStart` attribute. I can filter on equality, but am failing to filter on a range or partial value. The goal being to find all accesslog entries after a certain date/time.

With a value of `reqStart: 20180213144256.000008Z`, the filter `(reqStart=20180213144256.000008Z)` works but the following do not:

- `(reqStart>=20180213000000)`
- `(reqStart=20180213*)`

Answer (score 0):

I asked too soon; I found my answer by going back to the man pages (`man slapo-accesslog`) and re-reading.
`reqStart` uses the `generalizedTime` syntax which after a quick skimming on [ldapwiki.com](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/GeneralizedTime) shows that I needed to append the timezone in order to compare with `>=`. These are filters that do work:

- `(reqStart>=20180213000000Z)`
- `(reqStart>=20180213000000-0600)`

The minimum requirements for this syntax is `century year month day hour timezone`, so the following is the minimum that would work:

- `(reqStart>=2018021300Z)`

Or for the -06:00 offset for my timezone:

- `(reqStart>=2018021300-0600)`

More details on the syntax at the link posted above.